# Assistance on automated image/text Document

Tags: python, user-interface, automation

#### Hello all

I work for an estate agents and I am looking for a way of easily creating window cards for the properties (similar to this: http://www.inhabit.com.au/scr/windowcard1.png)

I am interested in creating a program that takes the text and images of the property and places them in the correct positioning (so a lamen can use it). It would then need to be printed.

I am fimiliar with graphic software such as Inkscape to create a template but I won't be the only one using it.

Would anybody have any idea of where to start creating an automated program that would create a window card?

Much oblidged

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use weasyprint and python to create a such software.

You create first the HTML of the document, this is a template it won't move, so you only have to do it once, here is a basic template:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Trademark</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="photos">
        <img src="photo.jpg">
      </div>
      <div id="text">
        {{ text }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This script will write a file called `input.html` with the the `{{ text }}` area replaced by content of the text file. Mind the fact that you can add support for bold, italic even tables using markdown.

```
with open('card.html') as f:
    card = f.read()

with open('text.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

with open('input.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(card.replace('{{ text }}', text))
```

Once you have a `photo.jpg` and the text you can execute the above script followed by the following command:

```
 weasyprint -f png -s styles.css input.html output.png
```

This will generate something similar to:

[image: output of the script]

This requires better design, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you, I look forward to trying this, David